# Struggling to compile gdal with hdf4 support

Tags: bash, homebrew, gdal

I am unable to compile gdal with hdf4 support using bash on a mac osx el capitan version 10.11.6.  I began with the homebrew approach to building gdal described on the [osgeo website](https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/BuildingOnMac).  Unfortunately, hdf4 is not by default supported by gdal.  The [hdf format page](https://gdal.org/frmt_hdf4.html) includes a great description of the hdf4 data structure but fails to help getting support for gdal.  I've installed the szip, zlib, and jpeg libraries discussed [here](https://support.hdfgroup.org/ftp/HDF/releases/HDF4.2.5/obtain425.html), and reviewed the struggles described by /u/dschneiderch [here](https://github.com/OSGeo/homebrew-osgeo4mac/issues/109).  The github thread lead me to a final [link](https://web.archive.org/web/20190201133444/http://r-sig-geo.2731867.n2.nabble.com:80/OSX-rgdal-GDAL-drivers-and-HDF4-td7588400.html), which is the basis for my current post.

Using homebrew, I have installed hdf4 (`brew install homebrew/versions/hdf4` returns a warning that `versions` was deprecated and homebrew will use `science` instead).  I've been fighting with this gdal problem for a while, and sure enough, `homebrew/science/hdf4-4.2.11_2 already installed`.  So, I linked hdf4 using `brew link -overwrite-hdf4`, and a warning comes back that it's already been linked.

I used `brew remove gdal` to start fresh with the install, then followed Shaun's approach in the [sig-geo listserv](https://web.archive.org/web/20190201133444/http://r-sig-geo.2731867.n2.nabble.com:80/OSX-rgdal-GDAL-drivers-and-HDF4-td7588400.html) to complete the gdal installation.  Thus, my total workflow was:

```
brew tap homebrew/versions
brew install hdf4 
brew link --overwrite hdf4 
brew install gdal --complete --enable-unsupported --with-hdf4
```

Unfortunately, even after linking the overwrite, I get a warning: `Warning: gdal: this formula has no --with-hdf4 option so it will be ignored!`.  The installation continues, though, and homebrew is able to build gdal.

Checking `gdalinfo --formats`, hdf4 is still not included in the list.  Any tips for what else to try?

Answer (score 0):

I've made some progress using [this source](http://technical-notes-of-randerson-group.readthedocs.io/en/latest/gdal/), in that gdalinfo --formats' now includes HDF4 as a supported product. However, using pyModis to download data, I still pull a GDAL installation has no support for HDF4, please update GDAL` error.

Importantly, though, after installing Macport the following code works well for installing GDAL on Mac with HDF4 support:

```
 sudo port install gdal +hdf4 +hdf5 +netcdf
```