# how to install gdal with hdf4 support macos catalina (python)

Tags: python, gdal, macos-catalina, hdf

Can anyone suggest a straightforward way to install gdal with hdf4 support on macos catalina?

I have tried many ways and I am still not able to read hdf4.

1. I installed gdal via homebrew with [this](https://medium.com/@egiron/how-to-install-gdal-and-qgis-on-macos-catalina-ca690dca4f91) instruction. Apparently
   that gdal has no support for hdf4.
2. I tried installing gdal via Macports as suggested by a previous [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44346301/struggling-to-compile-gdal-with-hdf4-support) using `sudo port install gdal +hdf4 +hdf5 +netcdf`, but
   the installation failed with the following errors:

   > Error: Failed to build gdal: command execution failed Error: See /opt/local/var/macports/logs/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_macports_release_tarballs_ports_gis_gdal/gdal/main.log
   >   for details. Error: Follow
   >   https://guide.macports.org/#project.tickets to report a bug. Error:
   >   Processing of port gdal failed
   >   --->  Some of the ports you installed have notes:   netcdf has the following notes:
   >       As of version 4.2 c++ and fortran interfaces are separate ports, netcdf-cxx and netcdf-fortran, respectively.
3. I tried looking for solutions for the above errors and found none that matched mine. So i have given up on gdal.
4. I moved on to install pyhdf and pymodis - both failed. Pyhdf error was: Failed to build pyhdf
   ERROR: Could not build wheels for pyhdf which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly. For pymodis, it was successful, but obviously the GDAL I installed via brew has no support for HDF4 (Error: GDAL installation has no support for HDF4, please update GDAL
   WxPython missing, no GUI enabled).

Any help would really be good!

Answer (score 0):

I struggled to find an answer to this for days. I also gave up on the gdal approach and moved on to installing pyhdf but building from source was far more complicated than it was worth. I initially avoided using anaconda because I prefer to use virtualenv for managing virtual environments, however the easiest way to get pyhdf up and running is to:

1. install anaconda
2. create a new virtual environment
3. activate that new environment in a mac terminal window
4. run `conda install -c conda-forge pyhdf`

You will have to reinstall all your other required packages, which might be a pain but was quicker than figuring out the build from source option. Testye